# How to keep indentation in R markdown?

Tags: html, r, markdown

I am creating an html document with R markdown. I have many numbered points that are automatically indented. I want to be able to take a new paragraph below a numbered point but still have the paragraph indented so it lines up with the numbered point. How can I do this? If you look at my image you can see that the text goes further to the left when I take a new paragraph. The points below are still a part of point 14 but I just need them in a new paragraph. Thanks[image]

Comment: i believe you need to use the space , try giving the space

Answer (score 0):

As jkatam tersely said, "try giving the space". I interpret this to mean "indent the part to be indented.

Raw markdown:

```
The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s

- *"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."*

    *"Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."*

And something else not in the bullet-list.
```

Formatted HTML:

[image: rmarkdown rendered as HTML, with second paragraph in a bullet list]

Rendered using

```r
rmarkdown::render("doc.md", output_file = "doc.html", output_format = "html_document")
```